# Domain forwarding to appspot.com

Tags: google-app-engine, web-hosting

I have an app hosted on google app engine (app.appspot.com). I'm about to register a domain (www.example-domain.com).  Is domain forwarding the easiest way to ensure vistors to www.example-domain.com are taken to my app?

Are there any drawbacks?

I looked into Google Apps and it seems like I could do it that way for $5/month and get the email address etc. Is that a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use you CNAME to redirect to your site. I do myApp.myDomain.com. The trick to this is that www. is also a CNAME. So just change you CNAME for www. for your domain to point to your app!

For the details see:
http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/domain.html

Answer (score 2):

You need to put a CNAME record on your domain DNS that will point to ghs.google.com, more info [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/domain.html)

Comment: Thanks Shay. Would I still need to pay $5/month?

Comment: I don't know whats your contract with your DNS provider, but you won't pay 5$ to Google

Answer (score 0):

As stated, the best option is to set up the CNAME - as you correctly noted, you'll need a Google Apps account for this but you will only need the free version.

Also, you'll struggle to register www.appspot.com!! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the cname record for www, you may want to handle the naked domain (domain.com).  Some registrars provide a redirect service or you could use http://wwwizer.com/.